# error in file_get_content() in php

Tags: php

I m trying to generate a QR code with form values my problem is it's showing some error like:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.test.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=test1,test2 , test3): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in local path.

When I m running this code it will generate a QR-code with no data.

So far I have done this:

```
$datas = $_POST['data'];
$width = $height = 100;
$url   = implode(", ",$datas);
$qr_img = "<img src=\"http://www.test.com/chart?chs={$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chl=$url\" />";

$filename = "images/qr-code/qr-code.png";
$qr  = file_get_contents("http://www.test.com/chart?chs={$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chl=$url");
file_put_contents($filename, $qr);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: "url/chart..." is not a valid url.

Comment: this.lau_@ i know this is not a valid url, I hide my url because this post is public.hope you understand.

Comment: Can you access `http://www.test.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=test1,test2 , test3` in your browser? Also why there is white space in your url?

Comment: yes i can acces the url through browser. when i acces through the browser it will shows the qr code. am getting the chl values from a form.i think m not trimming the white space.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this line:

```
$url   = implode(", ",$datas);
```

is generating an invalid url. URLs passed as argument to another URL must be url-encoded:

```
$datas = $_POST['data'];
$width = $height = 100;

$url   = urlencode(implode(", ",$datas)); // encode invalid chars

$qr_img = "<img src=\"http://www.test.com/chart?chs={$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chl=$url\" />";

$qr  = file_get_contents("http://www.test.com/chart?chs={$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chl=$url");

$filename = "images/qr-code/qr-code.png";
file_put_contents($filename, $qr);
```

see also [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php): [urlencode in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)